# Reset or repair stand alone dehumidifier?

Tags: repair, appliances, dehumidifier

After working well for a few years, a stand-alone dehumidifier has stopped taking water out of my basement. The dehumidifier drip tube does not even get wet.

The noises tell me the fan and compressor are working.

Is there some reset or easy repair inside the plastic cabinet that I could try to get the dehumidifier working again?

(It is a Soleus or Sunpentown 65-Pint Dehumidifier SD-65E.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The dehumidifier has lost it's refrigerant charge. It will cost more to repair than to replace.